# How to get button inserted through CSS/Javascript via chrome extension to always display on top of other content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension where I insert an element (button) through some javascript/css. I want the button to always be visible at specific points but I'm finding that sometimes the button is hidden or only partially visible on some websites.

```
    // Place div in upper right
    var div = document.createElement('button');

        // Positioning
        div.style.position = 'fixed';
        div.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';
        div.style.display = 'block';
        div.style.zIndex = 100000000000000000000000000000000000;
        div.style.top = '140px';
        div.style.right = '20px';
```

In the CSS above, I made the zIndex very high thinking that it would force the button to always appear on top but I'm finding that this isn't happening (the picture attached in an example where this doesn't happen).

How do I get the button to always appear on top?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You also need to make sure that the parent element containing your DIV has a CSS `position` attribute defined? (i.e. relative)

Comment: How would I actually do that? Meaning in terms of the css/javascript I would incorporate above?

Comment: Have you tried div.style.cssText = ‘z-index: 999’

Comment: Can you show us the code that you use to append your DIV in the web page?

Comment: @leo.fcx document.body.appendChild(div);

Comment: @fencepencil that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Maximum z-index is 2^31-1 = 2147483647. Bigger numbers are either clamped into the range or, much worse, just the lower 32 bits are extracted.

Comment: @wOxxOm that worked! Do you want to write an answer below so I can give you credit?